# Is there any way to "backdate" requests to google server-side analytics?

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-analytics

I have an iOS app which can be used offline. I need to do anonymous page view tracking, so our customers can tell which pages people are most interested in (to drive future investments). So when the user is offline, we save a timestamped page view list, and if the user happens to be online when they use the app, we send these historic records up, and also do real-time tracking.

I'm keeping some summary statistics in my GAE app, so I can report the page views with historic accuracy. However, I'm *also* feeding these views into google analytics, using some python code I ported from google's server-side samples.

That all works great (except for language tracking, which I may have solved thanks to a separate question here on SO). However, I'd love for google analytics to be able to understand the historical hits in context. Right now, if I connect up after looking at several pages offline, GA thinks I just popped through a bunch of pages over the course of a couple seconds.

There is no documented utm variable for timestamping. The google analytics SDK for iOS (which I'm *not* using) has this ominous note:

> Known Issues
>
> Possible inaccurate timestamps: timestamps are recorded at the time the application dispatches to Google Analytics, so if a user experiences long periods of offline use, the timestamps may not be 100% accurate.

That seems like a bit of an understatement. Wouldn't offline timestamps be 100% inaccurate?

Anyway, the fact that the SDK doesn't handle this right makes me think I'm not going to be able to solve this. But I figured some SO wizard might have an idea...

Answer (score 0):

In fact, timestamp is a "relative" (client side) information used by Analytics to compute things like "time on page".

When the page is view in "absolute" (date and time) is always the time you send the request.